# How to make application insights ignore cancel

Tags: azure-application-insights

Gives a 500 response code when the cancel button is pressed multiple types by the users.

Not causing performance issues but just a lot of clutter in application insights.

Any way to filter this out would be helpful.

Nothing is shown in the telemetry to share too, only the API method that is been called with a 500 code and time. sharing the screenshot of that.   [image: is]

Comment: Your answer could benefit from additional context to make it clearer.

Comment: What's the kind of the project? .NET core web api or others?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the response code is 500, you can use [telemetry processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c) to filter out these kinds of request with code 500.

Assume you're using **.NET core**, you can follow the steps below:

Create a class which implements `ITelemetryProcessor`, then filter out the request whose response code is 500(or more conditions as per your need.). The sample code looks like below:

```
public class IgnoreCancelFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // next will point to the next TelemetryProcessor in the chain.
    public IgnoreCancelFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var request = item as RequestTelemetry;

        if (request != null &&
        request.ResponseCode.Equals("500", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
        // To filter out an item, return without calling the next processor.
        return;
        }

    // Send everything else
    this.Next.Process(item);
   }

}
```

Then, register it in `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup.cs` class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<IgnoreCancelFilter>();

}
```

If the programming language is not **.NET core**, you can find the proper method for .NET framework / js etc. in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is blocking all 500 errors. And in the real-world I want to see 500 when they really need to be addressed. Looking a way to filter the cancel request which is causing the azure to think it is an error which is not the case.

Comment: @ManaswiB, yes, this is blocking all 500 errors. My suggestion is that, you can debug when this kind of 500 cancel error, see is there any other properties which can be used to identify it.